# citation of papers

Tags: citing

Here is the preamble of the `.tex` document and I want to cite papers in my document. Please suggest me what to modify to do it.

```
\documentclass[paper=letter, fontsize=12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap} %Options: Sonny, Lenny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjarne, Bjornstrup
%\textwidth=450pt\oddsidemargin=0pt
%\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\onehalfspacing
```

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Citations_and_Bibliographies and https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=LaTeX/Bibliography_Management list several possible approaches. You can use a manual bibliography (with `thebibliography`), BibTeX and its `.bst` files (maybe with `natbib`, `cite`, ...) or  `biblatex`.

Comment: is it possible not to use biblatex?

Comment: Yes, as I said you can use manual `thebibliography` or BibTeX. I prefer `biblatex`, but there is no need to use it. Please have a look at the links in my first comment to learn about the possible methods.

Comment: I created a short tutorial about `biblatex` on YouTube, maybe it helps in the beginning: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYvS52511oQ&list=PL-Wl6F3zpJVwcDHK2rg9bDEEMjo70zp87